# I have error in program to count total number of objects with static variable

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
class Sample
{ int x;
  static int count;
   public:
  void get();
  static void showCount();
};
void Sample::get()
{
    cin>>x;
    ++count;
}
static   void Sample::showCount(){    
    cout<<"Total No. of Objects :"<<count;
}
 int main()
{ Sample s1,s2;
    s1.get();
    s2.get();
    Sample::showCount();
   return 0;

}
```

Compilation Error :[Error] cannot declare member function 'static void Sample::showCount()' to have static linkage[-fpermissive]

Comment: One more thing missing in your code is initialisation of `count`. Static member variables(here `count`) must be declared in the class and then defined outside of it.

Comment: It is by default  count=0  defined by the  compiler.

Answer (score 3):

**Remove static keyword**

```
void Sample::showCount(){    
    cout<<"Total No. of Objects :"<<count;
}
```

`static` keyword in a class member function declaration has a different meaning to `static` keyword in a function definition. The former tells that the function doesn't need an instance of the class (doesn't get `this` pointer), the later defines static linkage: local to the file, the function is accessible in this particular file only.

**You are also missing definition of count.** You need a line somewhere before `main`:

```
int Sample::count = 0;
...
main() {
...
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample
{ ...
    static void showCount();
};

static   void Sample::showCount(){    
    cout<<"Total No. of Objects :"<<count;
}
// You can void instead of static, because you are not returning anything.
```

This is incorrect. You don't need 2nd `static`.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring static member functions in C++, you only declare it as `static` inside the class definition. If you implement the function outside the class definition (like you have), don't use the `static` keyword there.

Outside of a class definition, the `static` keyword on a function or variable means that the symbol should have "static linkage." This means that it can only be accessed within the source file (translation unit) that it's in. `static` symbols aren't shared when all of your *compiled* source files are *linked* together.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) if you aren't familiar with the term "translation unit."

You have one other problem, which Saurav Sahu mentioned: you declared the static variable `static int count;` but never defined it. Add this outside of the class definition:

```
int Sample::count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Sample
{
    int x;
public:
    static int count;
    void get();
    static void showCount();
};
int Sample::count = 0;
void Sample::get()
{
    cin >> x;
    ++count;
}
void Sample::showCount(){
    cout << "Total No. of Objects :" << count;
}
int main()
{
    Sample s1, s2;
    s1.get();
    s2.get();
    Sample::showCount();
    return 0;
}
```